# Making an Underline in PHPPresentation

Tags: php, phppresentation

How to make an underline in PHPPresentation. I just wanted to make an underline for some of my text.

Can any of you let me know on this

Comment: If it's HTML, just use a CSS rule like `text-decoration: underline red;`

Comment: Was wondering about that too, but it clearly isn't: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation#getting-started .  Maybe ask the question over at the github repository? This seems to be a quite specific library question, and you'll probably get better help over at the repo.

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind my earlier comment, it can be done according to the docs.

```
$element->getFont()->setUnderline(Font::DASHED); // Pick a style
```

Styles and API are here: https://phpoffice.github.io/PHPPresentation/docs/master/classes/PhpOffice.PhpPresentation.Style.Font.html#method_setUnderline